# How to execute specific functions with input pattern in F# language

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data

I'm kinda new to F# and trying out a simple calculator app. I take input from the user, and I want to the specific functions to be executed as per the input.
Right now, whenever I take any input from user, the program executes top to bottom. I want it to execute only specific functions matching with the input. Like if input is 6 then body of scientificFun() should be executed. Right now it executes all functions. Please help, I'm kinda stuck on this one!
The code is

```
open System

let mutable ok = true
while ok do
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a operation:\n1.Addition\n2.Substraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n5.Modulo\n6.Scientific")
    let input= Console.ReadLine()  

    let add = 
        Console.WriteLine("Ok, how many numbers?")
        let mutable count = int32(Console.ReadLine())
        let numberArray = Array.create count 0.0
        for i in 0 .. numberArray.Length - 1 do
            let no = float(Console.ReadLine())
            Array.set numberArray i no    
    Array.sum numberArray
    let sub x y = x - y 
    let mul x y = x * y
    let div x y = x / y
    let MOD x y = x % y
    let scientificFun() = 
        printfn("1. Exponential")
    match input with
    | "1" -> printfn("The Result is: %f") (add)
    | "6" -> (scientificFun())
    | _-> printfn("Choose between 1 and 6")
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to use the calculator again? y/n")
    let ans = Console.ReadLine()
    if ans = "n" then
        ok <- false
    else Console.Clear()
```

Comment: Are you new to F# or to programming in general?

Comment: new to f# or functional paradigm

Comment: Of interest: [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

Comment: Of interest: [Calculator Walkthrough](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/calculator-design/)

Comment: Of interest: [Formula Calculator](http://fssnip.net/4Y) See line 235 - `let evaluate formula =`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `add` as function: `let add() =` or `let add inputNumbers =`

Otherwise this simplified version below only executes the functions corresponding to the input number:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 


    // define your functions
    let hellofun() =
        printfn "%A" "hello"

    let worldfun() =
        printfn "%A" "world"


    let mutable cont = true
    let run() =   // set up the while loop
        while cont do
        printfn "%A" "\nChoose an operation:\n 1 hellofunc\n 2 worldfunc\n 3 exit"
        let input = Console.ReadLine()  // get the input
        match input with // pattern match on the input to call the correct function
        | "1" -> hellofun()
        | "2" -> worldfun()
        | "3" -> cont <- false;()
        | _ -> failwith "Unknown input" 

    run()  // kick-off the loop
    0
```

The `[<EntryPoint>] let main argv =` is only necessary if you compile it. Otherwise just execute `run()`.